# How to provide an initial plotting platform to add additional plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to use a `for` loop to draw 3 side by side curves in R but without getting any error message nothing shows?

I suspect something should provide an initial plotting platform for the first curve, and then the second and the third plots can be added. Can the initial plotting platform be `plot.new()` for example?

Note: I'm definitely trying to avoid using long `if` `else` statements as a solution.

**Here is my R code:**

```
for(i in 1:3){

  p = c(.1, .5, .9)[i]
col = c("red3", "green3", "blue")[i]

curve( dbinom(x, size = 100, prob = p), add = T, ty = "h", xlim = c(0, 100), 
   col = col, xlab = "Number of Agreements", ylab = "Probability", las = 1 )

}
```

Comment: You don't define `x` in your code. I would recommend generating all your data upfront, then plotting all at once. This way the initial plotting device can be created with axis limits that fit the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you'd like to avoid `if` statements, how about

```
p = c(.1, .5, .9)
col = c("red3", "green3", "blue")

for(i in 1:3) curve(dbinom(x, size = 100, prob = p[i]), add = i!=1, 
    ty = "h", xlim = c(0, 100), col = col[i], 
    xlab = "Number of Agreements", ylab = "Probability", las = 1 )
```

Comment: the `i!=1` is actually logical - it has a value of `TRUE` if `i` is not equal to 1

Answer (score 0):

The first insertion occurs error because the curve does not exist. If you want a simple solution, follow the one below:

```
for(i in 1:3){

  if(i == 1){
  p = c(.1, .5, .9)[i]
  col = c("red", "green", "blue")[i]

  curve( dbinom(x, size = 100, prob = p), ty = "h", xlim = c(0, 100), 
         col = col, xlab = "Number of Agreements", ylab = "Probability", las = 1 )
  }else{
    p = c(.1, .5, .9)[i]
    col = c("red", "green", "blue")[i]

    curve( dbinom(x, size = 100, prob = p), add = T, ty = "h", xlim = c(0, 100), 
           col = col, xlab = "Number of Agreements", ylab = "Probability", las = 1 )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following:

```
for(i in 1:3){

  p = c(.1, .5, .9)[i]
col = c("red3", "green3", "blue")[i]

curve( dbinom(x, size = 100, prob = p), 0, 100, add = ifelse(i > 1, T, F), ty = "h", xlim = c(0, 100), 
   col = col, ylab = "Probability", xlab = "Number of Agreements", las = 1)
}
```